# Need to bind an inner function to the click event of an element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to use a "resetMap" function which I defined in my initMap function (callback function for google map), to bind to reset button. Now it cannot be used because its not there in the global scope.
If I move this function to global scope its items such as mapOptions.center setzoom etc will be undefined.

This is my script file

```
var map;

/* Hardcoding 5 airport locations - our data - model*/
var airports = [
    {
        title: "Calicut International Airport",
        lat: 11.13691,
        lng: 75.95098,
        streetAddress: "Karipur",
        cityAddress: "Malappuram, Kerala",
        visible: ko.observable(true),
        id: "nav0",
        showIt: true
    },
    {
        title: "Chennai International Airport",
        lat: 12.9920434,
        lng: 80.1631409,
        streetAddress: "Meenambakkam",
        cityAddress: "Chennai, Tamil Nadu",
        visible: ko.observable(true),
        id: "nav1",
        showIt: true
    },
    {
        title: "Trivandrum International Airport",
        lat: 8.4829722,
        lng: 76.909139,
        streetAddress: "Vallakkadavu",
        cityAddress: "Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala",
        visible: ko.observable(true),
        id: "nav2",
        showIt: true
    },
    {
        title: "Cochin International Airport",
        lat: 10.15178,
        lng: 76.39296,
        streetAddress: "Nedumbassery",
        cityAddress: "Kochi, Kerala",
        visible: ko.observable(true),
        id: "nav3",
        showIt: true
    },
    {
        title: "Kempegowda International Airport",
        lat: 13.2143948,
        lng: 77.6896124,
        streetAddress: "Devanahalli",
        cityAddress: "Bengaluru, Karnataka",
        visible: ko.observable(true),
        id: "nav4",
        showIt: true
    }
];


/* Initializing map, markers */
function initMap() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.2143948, 77.6896124);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(8.4829722, 76.909139), //SW coordinates here
        new google.maps.LatLng(13.2143948, 77.6896124) //NE coordinates here
    );

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    setMarkers(airports);
    setMapWithMarker();

    /* Function to reset the map zoom and set center */
    function resetMap() {
        map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        map.setZoom(6);
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
    });
}

/* Controlling the visibility of marker based on the 'showIt' property */
function setMapWithMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
        if(airports[i].showIt === true) {
            airports[i].locMarker.setMap(map);
        } else {
            airports[i].locMarker.setMap(null);
        }
    }
}

/* Setting markers on map and attaching content to each of their info windows */
function setMarkers(location) {
    var img = 'img/airport.png';
    for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
        location[i].locMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[i].lat, location[i].lng),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: location.title,
            icon:img
        });

        var airportTitle = location[i].title;
        var wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' +
        airportTitle + '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';

        (function(i){
            var wikiRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.show-error').html('ERROR: Failed to load wikipedia data - Airport details will not show up! Sorry for the inconvenience caused.');
            }, 5000);

            $.ajax({
                url: wikiUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }).done(function(response){
                var article = response[2][0];
                    location[i].contentString =
                    '<strong>'+ location[i].title + '</strong><br><p>' + location[i].streetAddress
                    + '<br>' + location[i].cityAddress + '<br></p><p>' + article +
                    '</p><p>Source: Wikipedia</p>';
                    clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout);
            });
        })(i);

        /* info window initialization and setting content to each marker's info window */
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

        new google.maps.event.addListener(location[i].locMarker, 'click',
            (function(airport, i) { return function() {
                airport.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    airport.setAnimation(null);
                }, 2400);
                infowindow.setContent(location[i].contentString);
                infowindow.open(map,this);
                map.setZoom(15);
                map.setCenter(airport.getPosition());
            };
        })(location[i].locMarker, i));

        /* info window call when clicked on airport menu item */
        var searchNav = $('#nav' + i);
        searchNav.click((function(airport, i) {
            return function() {
                airport.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    airport.setAnimation(null);
                }, 2200);
                infowindow.setContent(location[i].contentString);
                infowindow.open(map,airport);
                map.setZoom(15);
                map.setCenter(airport.getPosition());
            };
        })(location[i].locMarker, i));
    }
}

/* Function for toggling the menu */
function slideToggle() {
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
    $( "#listing" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}

/* Our view model */
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.locMarkerSearch = ko.observable('');
    ko.computed(function() {
        var search = self.locMarkerSearch().toLowerCase();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(airports, function(airport) {
            if (airport.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0) {
                airport.showIt = true;
                return airport.visible(true);
            } else {
                airport.showIt = false;
                setMapWithMarker();
                return airport.visible(false);
            }
        });
    });
};

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I need to bind the function here in my index.html

```
<footer>
  <button id="reset" data-bind="click: resetMap">Reset Zoom to center</button>
</footer>

<script src="js/lib/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDVOVW9WT7QaVlFYDkE7K2Qm-AvSS02YrM&callback=initMap" async defer onerror="googleError()"></script>
```

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `// codes here` Kind of important to show us what's on your viewmodel, what with that being what you're binding! Are we supposed to guess how `viewModel` uses `initMap`?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us how `viewModel` uses `initMap`, but fundamentally, `initMap` needs to make `resetMap` available to the outside world. One way to do that is to return it:

```
function initMap() {
    // ...
    function resetMap() {
    }
    // ...
    return resetMap;
}
```

and then have code in `viewModel` put that on the view model:

```
function viewModel() {
    this.resetMap = initMap(); // I assume you're calling this indirectly; whatever
}
```

Then `resetMap` has access to what it needs, and it's on the view model so it can be bound.

Comment: Yeah this is along the right lines - essentially the OP needs to have a tighter coupling between the map and viewmodel.  Another way would perhaps be have `initMap` instantiate`viewModel` (and then call `applyBindings`) passing in `map` and `mapOptions`, then the `resetMap` function can solely exist in the viewmodel available for binding.  Best approach to take depends on what else is actually going on in the page and when these things are running, which as you've pointed out we can't really see....

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Yeah. Or we pass the view model instance into `initMap` (or whatever calls `initMap`), etc.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in JS, I have edited the code now you can see full script file and initMap is passed as a callback only.. No connection in viewmodel.. pealse check.. @JamesThorpe